# Need to move the location of an appended view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list that gets sorted by using absolute positioning. The problem is that a user clicks on a li it supposed to open an appended view, which unfortunately is also needing to be abs pos. I found the JS where this appended and tried changing it from

```
this.$item.append(this.getEl());
```

to

```
$('#myGrid').append(this.getEl());
```

So that it was no longer being opened in the absolutely positioned this.$item. but this breaks the functionality of the rest of the script.

Is there a way to allow it to keep its scope but be moved somewhere else in the dom once it is appended. Or is there better way to approach this?

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: What do you mean with "open an appended view"? As @jhyap pointed a fiddle or the real site seems necessary to realize what do you mean.

Comment: a abs positioned div is the view i am referencing

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding some things you said: "open an appended view", "keep its scope", "moved somewhere else in the dom" means nothing for me without some kind of enviroment. I'd like to help, but I can't without more background information.

Comment: totally understand, it can all be rather nebulous. I found a workaround for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to move the element after it was added. Not ideal but this might help others dealing with absolute positioned elements that are children of another absolute positioned elements

```
$(".og-expander").appendTo("#myGrid");
```